# MongoDB advise request

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm going to implement a social web site for skill sharing, with (hopefully) millions of users and tens of millions documents.
My team and me are very attracted by NoSQL solutions, and by MongoDB in particular.
Though nobody in our team has any NoSQL experience, so we are scared about the steepness of our learning curve...
I ask:

- would you recommend us to go with NoSQL, or stay - with a more conservative approach - with MySQL?
- if yes, which learning approach would you suggest for us to keep (self-learning, courses, specialists hiring, ...?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use whatever technology your team is most comfortable with. At the begining, scale won't matter and getting the application out the door as fast as possible is *MUCH* more important.

Moving to a different persistence store later is not too tough (if you keep things clean).

Don't solve problems you don't have right now.